# A doubt from "Geometry of the complex of curves II: Hierarchical structure" by Masur and Minsky

Tags: curves-and-surfaces, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

In the paper "Geometry of the complex of curves II: Hierarchical structure" ([Paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807150)) there is a construction of curve complex for an Annular subdomain (2.4). The construction depends on the domain itself but the definition of domain consist of isotopy classes of subsurfaces. So I have the following doubts.

**1) Why the construction is unique upto isotopy?**

**2) Curves are considered upto isotopy, then what do they mean by 'The' core curve?**

**3) The vertices of curve complex are isotopy classes of curves. Then  why the function $\pi_Y$ defined in the next paragraph is well defined?**

PS: In para 2.3 they said that "to make discussion clear one *might* fix a complete hyperbolic metric on $S$." So does this metric assumption is necessary for those constructions or we can do them topologically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Why the construction is unique upto isotopy?

Recall that $S$ is the surface and $Y$ is the annular subsurface.  Masur and Minsy take an annular cover $\tilde{Y}$ and work there.  The cover $\tilde{Y}$ depends only on the free homotopy class of any core curve $\alpha \subset Y$.

> 2) Curves are considered upto isotopy, then what do they mean by 'The'
>   core curve?

They define "curve" in the first sentence of page 12.  Also, note that they write $\alpha \in C_0(S)$, so they mean the isotopy class.

It is standard practice to use the same notation for curves and their isotopy classes.  Tracking the difference between $\alpha$ and $[\alpha]$ is often not necessary.  I grant that this abuse of notation can cause confusion the first time you see it.

> 3) The vertices of curve complex are isotopy classes of curves. Then
>   why the function $\pi_Y$ defined in the next paragraph is well defined?

The definition of the "curve complex" $C(Y)$ is altered when $Y$ is an annulus.  Instead of using isotopy classes of essential curves they use isotopy classes rel endpoints of essential arcs in the Gromov closure of $\tilde{Y}$.  The classes downstairs (in $S$) lift to the correct classes upstairs (in $\hat{Y}$, the Gromov closure).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. But I am still confused about the third part. The Gromov clouser requires the cover to have a negatively curved metric right! So are we considering $\bar{Y}$ as a quotient of $\mathbb{H}^2?$ because then it is same as considering a hyperbolic metric in $S$.

Comment: You can do things this way.  However, taking the Gromov closure only requires that the metric space in question be $\delta$-hyperbolic.  It is an exercise to check that for any metric $\rho$ on $S$ (with $\chi(S) < 0$) the annular cover is $\delta$-hyperbolic.  (However, it is true that $\delta$ depends $\rho$.)

Comment: Again thanks. Actually I was trying to understand this from a complete topological background, so I was trying to avoid any use of geometry.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "It is a non-trivial exercise..."

Comment: Its okay. I knew that result.

Comment: You have to use some geometric notion to track projections to annular domains, because annuli don't have enough topology.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I have realized from your comment. I was actually missing this point. Thanks again.